# Is it possible to use grayscale images to existing model?

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

From [tensorflow's object recognition (R-CNN)](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/object_detectionR-CNN)

I'm re-training the existing model with new categories: the types of clothes (jeans, pants, blouse, and so on). Since we don't need colors to determine the type of clothes that user is wearing, I want to re-train it with gray-scale images. Is it possible to use gray-scale images to train existing model (which are trained with color images)?

I'm concerned because they trained their model with **color images**.

Does the model just consider the grayscale image as color image? And does it still work? :)

p.s I'm generating XML and csv files to put data for training and testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you will need to add another 2 channels to your 1 channel gray input images, just clone your gray image 3 times, and merge these as 3 channel image. Anyway, you need 3 channel input images to use model trained with color images.

Comment: In my case, I'm generating XML and csv files to put data for training and testing. So in my understanding, I can't add two more channels.. I'm following this video... ! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kq2Gjv_pPe8

Comment: Your answer is correct but I think my question was not concrete. Could I ask you again with this question again? :)

Comment: Does the model just consider the grayscale image as color image? And does it still work? :)

Comment: I think in training set of the model you want to use as base present not only full color images, but gray also, so it may be faster to fine tune existing network trained with color images, with your gray images. But network input is for 3 channels, and you'll need to transform you dataset accordingly anyway. And yes, I think it should work. But if you want to use just 1 channel images, you need change input layer, and retrain full network from scratch.

Comment: Make Sense! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

You can clone 1 channel of the gray image to other 2 channels by `tf.tile`, here's some code example:

```
images = tf.tile(images, [1, 3])
summary_images = tf.transpose(tf.reshape(images, [-1, 3, 28, 28]), (0, 2, 3, 1))
```

`images` is tensor with dimension `N * 784` `N` is the batch size, image origin size is 28 * 28